# Are there callbacks on the Jquery Datatables Export buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

So I just implemented jquery datatables and added the export buttons.
I was wondering if there are any callbacks on export. Let say I have a list of items in the database that i am showing in the datatable and I want to remove them from the database after i have exported them.

Please any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

No not as far as I know.
But you can create your own custom [Button](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/custom) and define an [action](https://datatables.net/reference/option/buttons.buttons.action) for it. Inside that action you can call the export function and afterwards do whatever you are up to.

```
new $.fn.dataTable.Buttons( table, {
    buttons: [
        {
            text: 'Create CSV',
            action: function ( e, dt, node, config ) {     
                // Call the default csvHtml5 action method to create the CSV file
                $.fn.dataTable.ext.buttons.csvHtml5.action.call(this, e, dt, node, config);                 

                // Do custom processing
                alert('Other stuff');
            }
        }
    ]
} );
```